# Casino Game in Video game

Tags: probability

### Backstory

---

I'm making this post in regards to a video game I play and it has a gambling system within it and I'm not the greatest at stats and believe the way I bet is flawed but would like to find the most optimal way of betting. This is probably straight forward so sorry if this is a simple question.

### The Gambling Wheel

---

A wheel spins **every 45 seconds** and you are able to bet on **5 different numbers** with different frequencies:

| Number | 1 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Probability | 48% | 24% | 16% | 8% | 4% |
| Winnings | 2x Bet | 4x Bet | 6x Bet | 11x Bet | 21x Bet |

you are allowed to bet on all the numbers at the same time and you are **allowed to bet 1 - 2000 on each number**.

### My Strategy

---

So how I approached this was by ignoring every other number except 1, since its my most likely way of winning being 2% short of being a coin flip.

I would start with betting **8** first, if I won id then bet **8** again, if I loss id double it and bet **16** and this would continue on. so my betting would look like

- 8
- 16
- 32
- 64
- 128
- 256
- 512
- 1024
- 2048

If I kept losing, I've never had to bet past 256 though in hours of using this method.

Now is there a more efficient way of betting or is there some way that you can make a smarter bet in this if you had additional money to bet high?

Comment: (1) Repeated doubling is a satisfactory strategy only for those of unlimited wealth. Even gambling casinos discourage or prohibit patrons from using it. (2) Stay away from bets on 10 and 20. (3) What assurance do you have that the numbers appear randomly and with the advertised probabilities? At casinos, there is often governmental oversight that purports to watch for games with falsely advertised odds.